# The object reference error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am using the following code on page_load event in asp.net

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          lblDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
          if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                setImageUrl();
            }             

        }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setImageUrl();
    }

    private void setImageUrl()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        Image1.ImageUrl ="~/SlideImages/"+ i.ToString() + ".gif";


    }
```

code is working well at page-load event but when i click any other menu item it gives me the following error message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Amy - the error message should provide more detail than what you have posted, including the line number / code line that causes the null reference exception.  Can you include that in your post?

Comment: Image1.ImageUrl ="~/SlideImages/"+ i.ToString() + ".gif";                                  this is the line which is showing the error

Comment: Are these "other menu items" partial page loading?  Basically, it sounds like the page is losing the reference to `Image1` when you are navigating between pages.

Comment: Either Image1 or its i  that is null and you are calling to string on null object

Answer (score 0):

Well I am 95% sure that *i* is null because when you ToString() and object if it is null it will throw a fatal exception.  What I would do is set a break point on the line throwing the error and run this project in debug mode and see what I is returning.  If it is null then there is your problem.  So you would have to find out why your Random Method isn't instantiating properly.

Also a recommendation would be to do a String.Format on that line as well

```
Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("~/SlideImages/{0}.gif", i);
```

This will give you the same result set as long as *i* is valid and String.Format will format null as an empty string. So you will have a graceful fail and your image just won't show up which means you know your problem.